# When to use IEnumerable vs IObservable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, system.reactive

How do you establish whether or not a method should return `IEnumerable<T>` or `IObservable<T>`?

Why would I choose one paradigm over the other?

Comment: That's like asking how to decide whether a method should return a List<int> or a DateTime... The types aren't semantically related.

Comment: I agree with @MatthewWatson, both interfaces serves different purposes.

Comment: They are both used to enumerate data streams - so when do I decide whether or not I should use one or the other?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is for *pulling* data from a collection, `IObservable` is for subscribing to for *pushed* data.

Comment: They are not both enumerating. IEnumerable is basically like "give me the next item", IObservable is "hey look, there is the next item".

Comment: That's not necessarily the case. That's more of a hot observable vs cold observable thing.

Comment: @user2346896 IEnumerable<T> represents a sequence of separate items; IObservable<T> represents a temporally-dependent sequence of change events associated with a single item.

Comment: I would argue that IObservable<T> and IEnumerableIObservable<T> are *very* semantically related. They might be opposing in many respects, but that doesn't mean they are unrelated. In fact Eric Meijer has done several talks on this very point, a video of one can be found here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Brian-Beckman-and-Erik-Meijer-Inside-the-NET-Reactive-Framework-Rx - it's also not a dumb question. There are many situations in which a choice between one or other has profound implications on a system's design.

Comment: Oops... spotted a typo. Previous comment should have started "I would argue that `IObservable<T>` and *`IEnumerable<T>`*..." etc

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Types

- `IEnumerable<T>`

  - You repeatedly "pull" from a sequence of `T`'s
- `IObservable<T>`

  - A sequence of `T`'s is being "pushed" at you

> Why would I choose one paradigm over the other?

You typically *don't* "choose" one paradigm over the other. Usually one stands out naturally as the correct choice, with the other one not making any sense.

## Examples

Consider the following examples:

- A huge CSV text file has an item on each line, and you want to process them one at a time without loading the entire file into memory at once: `IEnumerable<List<string>>`
- You are running an HTTP web server: `IObservable<WebRequest>`
- You want to do get the nodes of a tree data structure in a breadth-first manner: `IEnumerable<Node>`
- You are responding to user interface button clicks: `IObservable<Click>`

In each of these examples (especially the `IObservable<T>` cases), it just wouldn't make sense to use the other type.

## But what if I want to use the "other" type...

### `IObservable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`

If something is naturally an `IObservable<T>` but you want to process it as if it were an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can do that with this method:

```
IEnumerable<T> Observable.ToEnumerable(this IObservable<T>)
```

- When a `T` gets "pushed" by the `IObservable<T>`, it gets sent into a queue.
- When you try to "pull" a `T` out of the `IEnumerable<T>`, it blocks until the queue isn't empty, then dequeues.

### `IEnumerable<T>` to `IObservable<T>`

If something is naturally an `IEnumerable<T>` but you want to process it as if it were an `IObservable<T>`, you can do that with this method:

```
IObservable<T> Observable.ToObservable(this IEnumerable<T>)
```

- A thread from the .NET thread pool will repeatedly try to "pull" a `T` from the `IEnumerable<T>`.
- Each time it "pulls" a `T`, it "pushes" it at you via the `IObservable<T>`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `IObservable<T>` if you want to *push* data to callers of your method *at your convenience*. You do this by calling `OnNext()` on `Observers` that registered interest via `Subscribe()`.

Use `IEnumerable<T>` if you want callers of your method to *pull* data *at their convenience*. They do this by calling `GetEnumerator()` to acquire an `IEnumerator` and calling `MoveNext()` and `Current` (`foreach` compiles to this).

UPDATE: Perhaps best to give some examples:

A function that returns currency prices in a bank is a good candidate for `IObservable<T>`. Here the information is time-critical. As the server of this data, you need to get it to the client as soon as possible. The client won't know when that data is ready. So you push it to them.

A function that returns the valid trading days for a particular financial instrument and is used to populate the blackout days on a calendar control is a good candidate for IEnumerable. This data rarely changes and the client (setting up the control) prefers to consume it at a pace it dictates.

Comment: This is correct, but why would I choose one paradigm over the other?

Answer (score 5):

[`IObservable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx) is a specialized interface that can be used for pub/sub and various other patterns.  You would know when you needed to return an `IObservable<T>`, so if there is not specific need then return `IEnumerable<T>`.

**Update to question in comment**

Basically, `IObservable<>` uses a "Push" mechanism and IEnumerable<> uses a "Pull" mechanism. If you are going to simply obtain a list of data that doesn't need to notify subscribers of changes (push) then you can use `IEnumerable`. If a subscriber (Window, Control, other Client programs/routines, etc...) needs to know when data changed then use `IObservable<>`. One example is using `IObservable` to update the main UI thread in a windows program from a child thread (Normally this cannot be done without fancy footwork.  Read up on .NET Reactive Extensions (Rx.NET).

Comment: Why not always return IObservable<T> instead of IEnumerable<T>? Surley IObservable<T> is a superset of the functionality?

Comment: Not correct. You're describing Observable<T> (the class). IObservable<T> is merely an interface that provides change notifications - not necessarily to do with collections.

Comment: Added answer to your question above....  Thanks for catching that Simon - I'm tired and meant to write class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IEnumerable<T>` to represent lists, use `IObservable<T>` to represent events. Easy peasy.